# Possible to call action method (from action method) and let ASP.Net Core inject [FromQuery] params?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a route `/my/route?t=something&...` which is handled by an action method which then switches on `t` and calls an appropriate subroutine to do whatever needs doing. Eg:

```
[HttpGet("my/route")]
public IActionResult GetStuff([FromQuery(Name = "t")]string searchType)
{
    switch (searchType)
    {
        case "type1":
            return getStuff_type1();
        case "type2":
            return getStuff_type2();
        default:
            return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

However, each subroutine expects other query params (some/many of which can be different depending on the subroutine's needs).

So, `"type1"` may accept query params "a", "b", "c", "d"; and `"type2"` may accept query params "v", "w", "x", "y", "z".

Obviously I could pull all the params (abcdvwxyz, and more for other types) into the main action method `GetStuff` and pass them into the subroutines as appropriate, but this is cumbersome/messy.. it would be nice if I could somehow call the subroutines and just let them specify their desired query params so the main `GetStuff` wouldn't have to care (this would probably need to use some ASP.Net Core IoC functionality to allow the subroutine's `[FromQuery]` params to be fulfilled).

Another option would be for the subroutines to simply use `Request.Query` to grab their desired params, but this doesn't declare/document the input values for the routine - which isn't as nice for testing or code clarity.

**Question is, does ASP.Net Core have functionality to allow handing off a request to another, specific, action method (and fulfill any necessary dependency injections)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, no. However, all action params are optional (they'll be filled with defaults, if not provided), so the suggested method of just accepting all the params is probably your best bet. If that's unacceptable, you can fallback to getting them manually out of `Request.Query`, but you'll need to do your own validation/binding with that (they'll all just be strings there).

That said, based on your problem description, your best bet is to actually use separate routes. You're essentially fighting a bit with how request-resource mapping is supposed to work with HTTP. If you have different types of searches, each requiring different params, then those could be considered each unique resources. Each one is doing something different and requires different input. Consider a lower-level example where you were doing all this directly on a domain model, without the HTTP layer. How exactly would you handle the logic? Would you have just one method to handle all the possible search types? Probably not. Even if you did, how would you provide params in that case? Wouldn't you still need to allow all possible params to be supplied?

Long and short, I'd remove this proxy action, and expose each individual search type method as an action. The search type could be a route param. Then, if you *really* wanted to, you could still have a proxy action that simply took the search type from the query and redirected to the appropriate search type route, along with the remaining portion of the query.

Comment: Yup, I agree having unique routes is nicer.. that was (and still is) my first choice. I was playing around with different ways of doing things (while figuring out my API route design) and was curious if the functionality in question was possible. Thanks for the answer and the encouragement to keep with separate routes (though I'm not entirely sure about my route schema yet.. but that's another question).